# Use Dojo date picker on iOS devices instead of native picker - XPages Feature Pack 8

Tags: dojo, xpages

We have an XPages (web) application which includes a date field.  When editable the field gets rendered automatically with a dojo-based date picker popup, which works on a desktop and iPad.

Since installing Feature Pack 8 the default behaviour of the date picker when accessed from an iPad has changed to use the native iOS date picker instead (via the HTML5 attribute).  Prior to feature pack 8 it use the dojo-based date picker button/popup.

How do we go back to how it was before and enforce the dojo datepicker on the iPad?  There are some comments around date picker behaviour in the feature-pack 8 release notes but they are around the use of the mobile theme which we are not using in this instance.

Thanks.